# Setting model from action in Ember route

Tags: ember.js

I am calling an event like so:

```
{{#each}}
  <div class='row'>{{name}}  <a {{action showModal this}} href="#">Open modal</a>
{{/each}}
```

and have this route but NEED to set the model for the modal view but nothing seems to work. How can I get this to work?

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events: {
        showModal: function(obj) {
            var v = this.container.lookup('view:modal');
            // this.get('controller').set('model',obj); nope
            v.appendTo(Emberjs1.rootElement);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set properties directly on the view and access them in your view's template using the `view.property`

```
  var v = this.container.lookup('view:foo');
  v.set('bar', 'hello');
  v.appendTo(App.rootElement);
```

Then in the template it'd be

```
  {{view.bar}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qofoxazu/1/edit

If you really felt like create a controller/model you could get a controller, set the model on the controller, then set that model on your view.

```
  var v = this.container.lookup('view:foo'),
      controller = this.container.lookup('controller:foo');
  controller.set('model', 'hello');
  v.set('controller', controller);
  v.appendTo(App.rootElement);
```

Then your controller will be in scope and you wouldn't have to use `view` to access the properties.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qofoxazu/2/edit

Comment: thx kingpin - a quick question though. If you take out the FooController in your jsbin, it doesn't work (gets an undefined). I thought Ember would create that controller if it didn't exist. Why is that?

Comment: It only generates a default object/array controller when you don't name a specific controller.  In my example I'm naming a particular controller type, `foo`.  Anytime you name a particular controller you want to use, Ember complains if it can't find a particular controller by that name.

Comment: Creating dynamic views doesn't automatically create a controller, or assign properties to the view.  Hence you have to get a controller to assign a controller to the view being dynamically created.  And to get a controller, you need a controller type to  get (or you could be lazy and just do `var controller = Ember.ObjectController.create();`

Comment: thx kingpin, so the auto-object generation doesn't apply in this case only in the prebuilt view scenario? things like that are the confusing parts of Ember